# Unable to connect Robo 3T to a remote MongoDB server

Tags: mongodb

I'm using Mongo DB Version 3.4.6 on my Windows 7 laptop. I connect to MongoDB using Robo 3T version 1.1.1. I am trying to use Robo 3T to connect to a remote Mongo server.

I have edited the bind_Ip option in the mongo.conf file to include the IP Address of the remote server.

This is the error I receive:

> Failed to connect to No chance to load list of databases.

When I click on error details, this is what it says: Cannot connect to MongoDB at Error: Network is unreachable.

I am connecting via the default port 27017, which works when I try to connect Robo 3T to the MongoDB on my own laptop.

I have attached the error message that I receive.

[image]

Please help me address this issue.

Comment: Remote server where? It is pretty common that various providers of server infrastructure do not "publicly serve" addresses by default. Even if you do have a publicly accessible IP address for the server there typically would be some firewall adminstration required to allow access to the port. And typically, it's not a wise idea to publicly expose your MongoDB, and if you did then you probably should at the very least change the default port to something different and random in order to discourage hack attempts. Your provider should have more information.

Comment: Note that this really does border on the "off-topic" area for a programming or related tools question. Unless this stays very specific on "setting up the tool", then it would indeed be off-topic because the only other thing left to talk about is server and networking configuration. If you have an AWS instance, then chances are you need an "ssh tunnel" to access a private IP. The rest is either freely available in the providers own help articles, or becomes a networking question for [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com) instead.

Comment: The remote server runs on the same network as mine. Authorization is not setup for MongoDB. Firewall does not prevent me from using Robo 3T for my local system for port 27017 so I'm thinking maybe it won't prevent for a remote server as well.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little late, but i was facing the same problem. After i tried a lot of things i solved it just removing the connection from the manage connections window.

[image]

Then create it again, i know it sounds dummy but it was the only thing that worked for me

Comment: This actually worked for me, so +1. I'm certain I had the same values as before; I suspect the Robo3T connection dialog is a little buggy. This was on Ubuntu.

Comment: yup, if you edit your settings, it's better to delete and create again, because the edited settings dont seem to persist.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue, just change bindIp to 0.0.0.0 and restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

Go Inside bin folder of MongoDB and run mongod command:- C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin then open command prompt at this location and run mongod command & then try to connect with Robo 3T . It works for me.

Also create data folder inside your C: drive & then create a db named folder inside data folder. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue in Mac and couldn't find mongodb.conf to set bindIp from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0.
I installed only Robo 3T and used it.
Resolved using :

```
     brew install mongo
     brew tap mongodb/brew
     brew install mongodb-community
     vi /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

Edit the bindIP in this file...By default it is present at /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf

```
     sudo mongod restart
     brew services start mongodb-community
```

Now in Robo 3T check if any TLS security settings are enabled.If yes, disable them and now try to connect. :)

Answer (score 0):

For the ones that are having issues connecting via URI on Ubuntu, here goes a tip: I gone to TLS tab, then I selected `Self-signed-certificate` Authentication Method.
Also, make sure you have filled the fields correctly in the Authentication tab. In this tab I selected Auth Mechanism `SCRAM-SHA-1` and worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Edit the `mongo.conf` file and comment the line:
`bindIp: 127.0.0.1`